# Is there a free tool which can help visualize the logic of a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, python-2.6, call-graph

I would like to be able to plot a call graph of a stored procedure. I am not interested in every detail, and I am not concerned with dynamic SQL (although it would be cool to detect it and skip it maybe or mark it as such.)

I would like the tool to generate a tree for me, given the server name, db name, stored proc name, a "call tree", which includes:

- Parent stored procedure.
- Every other stored procedure that is being called as a child of the caller.
- Every table that is being modified (updated or deleted from) as a child of the stored proc which does it.

Hopefully it is clear what I am after; if not - please do ask. If there is not a tool that can do this, then I would like to try to write one myself. Python 2.6 is my language of choice, and I would like to use standard libraries as much as possible. Any suggestions?

*EDIT:* For the purposes of bounty Warning: SQL syntax is COMPLEX. I need something that can parse all kinds of SQL 2008, even if it looks stupid. No corner cases barred :)

*EDIT2:* I would be OK if all I am missing is graphics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I just realized you might be looking for a Python library that can do this for you.  If so, I apologize for the dud answer lol, but if you're trying to visualize a DB so you can perform maintenance, then my answer is the same :) **

It's not free, but I assure you SQL Dependency Tracker from RedGate is well worth the money.  It produces a graph like you're describing, allowing you to see all the participants in every procedure, key, view, trigger, etc.  Awesome software:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/

I know you said free, but I was in the same boat as you several years ago and looked quite a bit for something that could do the job, free or not.  Until I found this software, nothing else could do what I needed.  I strongly encourage you to find the money for this tool if you need to do this sort of thing on a regular basis.

Comment: How much does it cost? And do they have a trial period?

Comment: ~$300.  14-day free trial.  I haven't found a single other tool that does what this does.  I found some that could produce diagrams by following relationships between tables, but that's where they stopped.  No other tool would actually read the code from the view/stored procedure/function to build dependency graphs, which is what I needed since I was looking at removing duplicate views, SPs, etc that had started cluttering up my DB.  This one does it for pretty much every type of object on the server.

Comment: I see you're still looking for an answer on this one.  Dependency Tracker apparently can export as XML.  Although I can't say for sure what that xml will look like, another user seems to have a found a solution for getting unique dependencies: http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?p=25396#25396 Their support also mentions exporting a dependency list in PDF format for reporting purposes:  http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=SQL%20Dependency%20Tracker&c=SQL_Dependency_Tracker/help/2.4/SDT_ExportingDependencyList.htm&toc=SQL_Dependency_Tracker/help/2.4/toc279529.htm

Comment: As far as running this sort of thing on a regular basis, you could use a program like AutoHotKey (or a number of other mouse/keyboard macro tools)  combined w/ Task Scheduler to run a job periodically that would open the software, click the necessary options, and then do the export.  That's a little convoluted, but I don't think it gets much better if you're using dependency tracker.

Comment: Just FYI, the official feature list explicitly mentions "Export XML definitions of dependencies for offline processing": http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/features

Comment: @pheedbaq As an add on to the above question, is there such a tool for Oracle databases?

Comment: @ChetterHummin Not quite, but they do have some tools for Oracle DBs. http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Management Studio to show the actual or estimated query plan.  It gives a graphical output that you can follow.  Here's a little primer: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1873

Update:

You can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to create data extracts in a graphical fashion.  You can also use Microsoft Biztalk Server to create complex graphical layouts that also extract data.  Finally, you can use Microsoft's WF to create automated processes in a graphical fashion that can do similar functions as Biztalk.  Alas, these aren't free :(.  If you have a MSDN subscription they are :)

Biztalk Map:
http://geekswithblogs.net/images/geekswithblogs_net/Chilberto/WindowsLiveWriter/BizTalkMapComparisonbetweenTableLoopinga_B5B9/image_6.png

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a start. This question has a bounty on it, so I would like to ask - how would I auto-extract data I need from the query execution plan using some sort of script? Is there a way to auto-run the query execution plan?

Comment: Hmm, the query execution plan isn't really designed to be a data extraction tool, it's really used to show you what steps that SQL Serve r took when running the query.  You can save the execution plan (right-click menu).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190646.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Negotiator Pro has a free lite version at www.aphilen.com
The full version is the only product out there that will find all dependencies and not stop after finding the first 10 child dependencies. Other products fail when there is a circular reference and just hang, these guys have covered this off. Also a neat feature is the ability to add notes to the diagram so that it can be easily distributed.
Full version is not cheap but has saved us plenty of hours usually required figuring out complex database procedures. apex also provide a neat tool